# PHP MVC шаблон, скрыть с помощью админки страницы для пользователя

Tags: php, html, ооп, mvc

Здравствуйте занимался созданием MVC шаблона и появился вопрос.
Админ панели есть форма с полями для создания страниц которые отображаются на сайте,а так же чекбокс is_published (принимающий значения 0 1), который должен отвечать за отображение/скрытие публикации для пользователя.
Не могу разобраться как и где мне добавить проверку, чтобы отображать или скрыть страницу...

Опишу весь алгоритм.

сам чек бокс:

```
    <h3>Add page</h3><br/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="is_published">Publish?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="is_published" id="is_published"  checked="checked" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

Изначально, при создании страницы чекбокс стоит вкл. в бд передается 1. и
он прикрепляется к конкретной странице.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
далее на странице где отображается контент стоит вызов:

```
<div class="starter-template">
        <?=$data['content']?>
  </div>
```

Сам контент получаем из класса view с помощью функции render:

```
public function render() {
        $data = $this->data;

        ob_start();
        include($this->path);
        $content = ob_get_clean();

        return $content;
    }
```

Отображение контента на шаблоне происходит в клессе app:

```
//выполнение рендеринга контента выводимого в дефолт хтмл

    $layout = self::$router->getRoute();
            $layout_path = VIEWS_PATH.DS.$layout.'.html';
            $layout_view_object = new View(compact('content'), $layout_path);
            echo $layout_view_object->render();
```

Весь код - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2CC-avi19RQOVN5dWl2eWdYeDg

13-14 урок по которому делал админку - devionity точка com урок : MVC. Собственный фреймворк с нуля!

Comment: `Собственный фреймворк с нуля!` и чё? Оно конечно похвально, но не более того. **PHP** -  http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php. **SQL** `SELECT * FROM название_таблицы WHERE is_published = 1 and id = ?`. А так ваш код разгребать не станут, добавьте в вопрос только тот код что нужно.

Comment: @E_p это вроде как название урока, а не восхваление самого себя

Comment: @webDev_ Меня наверное восклицательный знак сбил. Жаль комментарий не отредактируешь

Comment: Внес конкретики, вроде так проясниться суть вопроса...
Хвалений и тд не преследую, т.к. нечему... единственная цель развитие навыков и обучение.
,,Собственный фреймворк с нуля!,, - название урока... там же написано было)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел решение.

в модели, я доработал метод getList, который занимался получением данных из таблицы pages и там же стоит проверка на published.
собственно продублировал метод, и разделил их для админа и юзера.

таким образом получилось следующее:

```
public function getList_a(){
        $sql = "select * from pages where 1";
        return $this->db->query($sql);      
    }

public function getList_U($only_published = true){
        $sql = "select * from pages where 1";
        if ( $only_published ) {
            $sql .= " and is_published = 1";
        }
        return $this->db->query($sql);      
    }
```

Добавил более гибкий вариант

```
// by @E_p

const LIST_ALL = 2;
const LIST_PUBLISHED = 1;
const LIST_NON_PUBLISHED = 0;

public function getList($published) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages";

    switch ($published) {
        case self::LIST_PUBLISHED:
            $sql = . " WHERE is_published = 1";
            break;
        case self::LIST_NON_PUBLISHED:
            $sql = . " WHERE is_published = 0";
            break;
    }

    return $this->db->query($sql);
}

public function getNonPublishedList()
{
    return $this->getList(self::LIST_NON_PUBLISHED);
}

public function getPublishedList()
{
    return $this->getList(self::LIST_PUBLISHED);
}
```

соответственно для админа у нас будет свой метод который зависимо от 1 или 0 будет всегда выводить все страницы, а у юзера же будет отображаться только та страница у которой параметр 1.

Comment: На правах codereview. У вас сечас 2 одинаковых куска кода. А если надо будет сортировку добавить? Тоже в два места писать? А если появиться 3-й тип пользователя? 3-й раз повторять?

Comment: Ну и название функций неправильное семантически. Правильнее `getPublishedList` ,`getNotPublishedList`

Comment: согласен,учту, пока нашел именно такой выход...
а насчет названий не совсем понял, они у меня в обоих случаях published, только в одном проверка игнорируется, а в другом нет... ну и для использования более ясно, что _а для админа , ну и тд.

Comment: В том то и дело вы выбираете не посты для админа, а посты которые не published! Т.е. админ к постам меет ноль отношения, поэтому и не надо в название функции это вносить!

Comment: понял о чем вы. (надеюсь ^^` )

Comment: Добавил более гибкий вариант ^^

Comment: ого,попробую внедрить! спасибо!